# TypeScript or JavaScript for noob web developer

Tags: .net, javascript, typescript

Following the recent release by Microsoft of [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) I was wondering if this is something that should be considered for a experienced WinForm and XAML developer looking to get into more web development.

From reviewing a number of sites and videos online it appears that the type system for TypeScript makes more sense to me as a thick client developer than the dynamic type system in Javascript.

I understand that Typescript compiles down to JavaScript but it appears that the learning curve is shallower due to the current tooling provided by Microsoft.

What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Those aren't going to be the two options for a while. If you use TypeScript, you're going to need to know JavaScript anyway because, for the foreseeable future, there isn't going to be a tool for debugging TypeScript in the form it was written.

So it's JavaScript or TypeScript AND JavaScript.

So I suggest learning JavaScript first while keeping an eye on what TypeScript offers. While you're at it, take a look at what jQuery and CoffeeScript offer. The three packages solve different problems so, when you run into one of those problems, you'll know which product to learn next.

Comment: From what I've read on the subject so far, this sounds like good advice to me.

Comment: damn it, got to it before me :) +1

Comment: I appreciate your comments pdr. Although I do find JavaScript difficult to learn coming from the strongly typed .Net platform I was thinking that TypeScript may provide a middle ground and giving that it compiles into JaveScript would give me a better start with Javascript, jQuery and all the other libraries

Comment: @PhilMurray: Understand that sentiment, but I think you'll find it easier if you get to grips with the prototype-based nature of JavaScript, because TypeScript doesn't really do away with that. Worse, it might appear to and that will be very confusing.

Comment: you can debug TypeScript in the form it was written using [source maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12711826/debugging-typescript-code-with-visual-studio)